# What does "run" mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

> The number of adults doing weekly sport did rise by nearly 2 million in the **run**-up to 2012—but the general population was growing faster.

I consulted the dictionary but could not find a suitable meaning. Is "in the run" a phrase? In particular, what does "run" mean here?

Comment: I think the first dash is a typo for “... in the run-up to 2012 ...” meaning “in the period before 2012 ...”

Comment: No: "in the run" is not syntactic unit, not a constituent. Run-up" is a compound noun whose meaning is easy to find in a dictionary, see here:[link](https://www.lexico.com/definition/run-up)

Comment: This is a cross-post of an ELL question. Please do not post on multiple sites.

Answer (score 2):

You have to take it as a phrase. "In the run-up to" means "leading up to"

From [LexicalLab](https://www.lexicallab.com/2015/03/in-the-run-up-to/) -

> *The run-up to* a big event is the period of time before it

From [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/run-up) -

> The period preceding a notable event

Answer (score 1):

Please note the punctuation you originally used: you used an em-dash ("—") instead of a hyphen ("-"), and that drastically changed the sentence.

The ["run-up"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/run-up) (to something) is **the "final period of time before" (a notable event)**.

"Run-up" is a compound noun, like "build-up" and "show-off", which may be *hyphenated* (joined with "-"), *closed* (joined without punctuation, as in "Superman"), or *open* (left separate, as in "coffee mug").